# Unable to compile Unity WebGL after updating to Unity 2019.3

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors, unity-webgl

I have a Unity 2019.2 project the I just updated to Unity 2019.3, there were no errors in the editor upon opening the project, I can even build to Windows devices in a .exe form just fine. So I started developing some features, everything was fine, it still builds on Windows. so I try to switch my platform to WebGl. everything appears to be fine, I can even run my project. But as soon as I hit build, I get the following errors: (Each error is separated by a line)

```
Library\PackageCache\com.unity.xr.legacyinputhelpers@2.0.2\Runtime\TrackedPoseDriver\TrackedPoseDriver.cs(185,13): error CS1069: The type name 'PoseData' could not be found in the namespace 'UnityEngine.XR.Tango'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'UnityEngine.ARModule, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' Enable the built in package 'AR' in the Package Manager window to fix this error.

Library\PackageCache\com.unity.xr.legacyinputhelpers@2.0.2\Runtime\TrackedPoseDriver\TrackedPoseDriver.cs(186,17): error CS0103: The name 'TangoInputTracking' does not exist in the current context

Library\PackageCache\com.unity.xr.legacyinputhelpers@2.0.2\Runtime\TrackedPoseDriver\TrackedPoseDriver.cs(186,91): error CS0103: The name 'PoseStatus' does not exist in the current context

Error building Player because scripts have compile errors in the editor

Build completed with a result of 'Failed'
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: Error building Player because scripts have compile errors in the editor
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x00275] in <6f28216fea9f453abf2e05b770ed3ee4>:0 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in <6f28216fea9f453abf2e05b770ed3ee4>:0 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

After attempting to build in WebGL I can no longer run the project in the editor, however if I switch my platform back to Windows, the error disappears and I can run the project in the editor and even compile for Windows. but switching back to WebGL and trying to compile breaks it again.

It appears to have something to do with the way Unity 2019.3 is now based on packages, but I can't tell if it's a UI issue, input system issue, or any other number of endless issues. Can anyone else decipher the errors and offer a solution?

Edit: After trying to update the Unity XR in the Package Manager I now get the following errors, this time the errors come up just be switching the platform instead of having to build for it:

```
Library\PackageCache\com.unity.xr.legacyinputhelpers@2.0.6\Runtime\TrackedPoseDriver\TrackedPoseDriver.cs(188,13): error CS1069: The type name 'PoseData' could not be found in the namespace 'UnityEngine.XR.Tango'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'UnityEngine.ARModule, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' Enable the built in package 'AR' in the Package Manager window to fix this error.

Library\PackageCache\com.unity.xr.legacyinputhelpers@2.0.6\Runtime\TrackedPoseDriver\TrackedPoseDriver.cs(189,17): error CS0103: The name 'TangoInputTracking' does not exist in the current context

Library\PackageCache\com.unity.xr.legacyinputhelpers@2.0.6\Runtime\TrackedPoseDriver\TrackedPoseDriver.cs(189,91): error CS0103: The name 'PoseStatus' does not exist in the current context
```

Comment: Well it clearly says the xr package can’t find dependencies.

Comment: @BugFinder What it the xr package? It's not something I manually installed, so how do I install it?

Comment: You can find that package in PackageManager, take a look at my [screenshot](https://imgur.com/btAyKel). You can remove that if you don't need that or you can update that package to the latest version.

Comment: xr is not installed by default, so something installed it. However as Ankit said, you can remove it from package manager

Comment: @BugFinder I updated XR helper to 2.0,6, I've updated my original comment with the result. What does the XR helper do? I didn't installer it manually so if it did it would have had to have been something from the asset store, but the only think I have installed is Easy Notes.

Comment: @Ankit I updated XR helper to 2.0,6, I've updated my original comment with the result. What does the XR helper do? I didn't installer it manually so if it did it would have had to have been something from the asset store, but the only think I have installed is Easy Notes.

Comment: Is your App have any AR stuff in it? if not you can remove that plugin.

Comment: to be fair the errors havent changed if you dont think you use it, remove it

Comment: @Ankit Alright, I removed it, the project appear to be working fine, I don't know how the package got installed in the first place. Thank you though, for your help showing me what package the errors were pointing to and what it does. I've added an answer giving you and BugFinder credit for helping me, Thanks Again!

Comment: @BugFinder I removed it and it appears to be working fine, I don't know how the package got installed in the first place. Thank you for helping me identify what the issue was. I've added an answer giving you and Ankit credit for helping me, Thanks Again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way or another when updating to Unity 2019.3 it appears Unity automatically installed a package called "XR Legacy Input Helpers" [See Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGity.jpg), I tried updating the package by opening the Package Manager a updating the package, however this just caused more errors.

I found that removing the package worked since nothing was using it and I don't know why Unity even installed it. If I were using this package though I don't know what I would've done.

Thanks to @BugFinder & and @Ankit for helping me find the solution to my problems.

Answer (score 3):

After I upgraded a project from 2019.1 to 2019.3 I also got errors regarding

> Library\PackageCache\com.unity.xr.legacyinputhelpers@2.0.6\Runtime\TrackedPoseDriver\TrackedPoseDriver.cs

Similar to the answer by Jhon Piper, I found out that a non-needed dependency to `com.unity.xr.legacyinputhelpers` had been added.

The solution for me was to **remove this dependency**. 
Instead of using the package manager, you can also do this manually.
Here are the necessary steps for this:

1 - Open *projectfolder*/Packages/manifest.json

2 - You will see something like this:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "com.unity.2d.sprite": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.2d.tilemap": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.ads": "2.0.8",
    ...
  }
}
```

3 - In this file, remove the line that mentions the package `com.unity.xr.legacyinputhelpers` and save the file.